# How to trigger a login form notice message?

Tags: wp-login-form

How can I trigger a message box to appear on the login form?

I'l trying to get the little yellow notice bar to appear above the login form conditionally.

The below code only print the content on the page (duh, I know).

```
add_action('login_head', 'login_form_message');
function login_form_message() {
    echo 'Custom Login Form Message';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a filter to add messages there. You can sneak in messages that will than handled like an error message (without being one).

```
apply_filters( 'login_message', $message );
```

Here's an example of this filter:

```
function wpse79920_login_msg( $message )
{
    return 'Hello User!';
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'wpse79920_login_msg' );
```

Comment: Thank you! That lead me to this: http://www.jarrodpyper.com/blog/change-wordpress-login-message-filter-it-out/

Comment: @mattrepublic Wat? Don't get your point - didn't you want to add a message?

Comment: Yes, adding the `<p class="message">` put Hello user! in the box. I wouldn't have found that without the filter name you gave me. I'll be sure to dig deeper into filter next time.